# How send mysql rows to client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

im beginner in Node.js and i have a problem...
I dont know how send rows from server file to client file.
example:

```
var app = require("http").createServer(handler)
var fs = require("fs");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var url = require('url');

app.listen(1337);

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'wordpress1'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query("SELECT * FROM wp_comments", function(err, rows, fields) {
    rows[1].comment_author; // How send this to client file?
});

function handler(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
if(pathname === "/") {
fs.readFile('mysql.htm', function(err, content) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end(content);
});
  }
}
```

and client file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>dsfsd</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    // how to display a rows in this file?
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i heard something about common.js, require.js etc. but i dont know whether is this good way to build a node application?

Answer (score 2):

First, because node is all non-blocking, you have to reorganize the app code like this:

```
function handler(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    if(pathname === "/") {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM wp_comments", function(err, rows, fields) {
            // AS JSON
            res.send(rows);
            // Alternatives:
            // SERVER-SIDE TEMPLATE
            // res.render('mysql.htm', {comment_author: rows[0].comment_author})
            // BASIC FILE 
            // res.sendfile('mysql.htm')  
        });
    }
 });
```

If you want to use a server-side template engine to render the html, I suggest [jade](http://jade-lang.com/).  You could also receive the rows as JSON (which is how the above will actually send it as it stands) and then render it with a front-end templating engine, like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).